# Remove Gap of a Cell inside AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: apache-flex

I created an item renderer for a advanced datagrid and decided to put color on some of the cells. However the result comes with a vertical gap between the colored cell ( you can notice a big gap of white lines between the red cells on the screenshot)

Any idea how to remove this?

For the coloring of cell, I follow this tutorial [link](http://butterfliesandbugs.wordpress.com/2007/07/11/using-an-itemrenderer-to-change-the-background-of-a-datagrid-cell/).

[image]

Comment: Are you worried about the gap between columns?  Or the gap between rows?  Or both?

Comment: Only between rows. Somehow putting paddingTop , paddingBottom, verticalGap to 0 on the itemRenderer did not do the trick.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be an exposed property, so you'll probably need to look through and see where it is hardcoded and if it is possible to extend it and change that number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you set [paddingBottom](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/AdvancedListBase.html#style%3apaddingBottom) and [paddingTop](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/AdvancedListBase.html#style%3apaddingTop) to 0?  Docs make me think that these two properties control the gap.

Comment: I tried that already by putting it in my itemrenderer class ( see my comment ). I also thought that were the one control the gap.

Comment: @Rudy Set those styles on the AdvancedDataGrid; not your renderer.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try replacing g.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight) with g.drawRect(0, -2, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight+3)?